# iAd interstitial - Botão de fechar

Tags: ios, mobile, swift, apple

Estou tentando incluir um iAD fullscreen em um app, mas a tela de propaganda está aparecendo sem o botão de fechar, a duvida é se tenho que fazer ele a mão ou tem alguma opção oculta para isso?

Encontrei coisas mais antigas sobre isso, mas não sei se ainda refletem a realidade atual.

Segue a base do código que estou utilizando, mas em um arquivo "vazio".

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, ADInterstitialAdDelegate{

    var interstitialAd:ADInterstitialAd!
    var interstitialAdView: UIView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func chamarIAd(sender: AnyObject) {
        loadInterstitialAd()
    }

    func loadInterstitialAd() {
        println("loadInterstitialAd")
        interstitialAd = ADInterstitialAd()
        interstitialAd.delegate = self
    }

    func interstitialAdWillLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        println("interstitialAdWillLoad")
    }

    func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        println("interstitialAdDidLoad")

        interstitialAdView = UIView()
        interstitialAdView.frame = self.view.bounds
        view.addSubview(interstitialAdView)

        interstitialAd.presentInView(interstitialAdView)
        UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
    }

    func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        println("interstitialAdActionDidFinish")
        interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func interstitialAdActionShouldBegin(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        println("interstitialAdActionShouldBegin")
        return true
    }

    func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("interstitialAd")
    }

    func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        println("interstitialAdDidUnload")
        interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que solucionei meu problema. Vou deixar aqui para a pergunta ter uma resposta e para o caso de alguém ter uma solução melhor.

- Criei o botão de close dentro do método viewDidLoad:

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      closeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y:  20, width: 20, height: 20))
      closeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "close_button"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
      closeButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("close"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
  }
  ```
- Quando o iAd está sendo carregado, adiciono na view o botão close:

  ```
  func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
      interstitialAdView = UIView()
      interstitialAdView.frame = self.view.bounds
      view.addSubview(interstitialAdView)

      interstitialAd.presentInView(interstitialAdView)
      UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

      view.addSubview(closeButton)
  }
  ```
- Criei o método do botão, removendo o iAd e o botão close da view principal:

  ```
  func close() {
      interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
      closeButton.removeFromSuperview()   
  }
  ```